# Laravel remove id and timestamps from pivot

Tags: laravel

I created a pivot table and accidentlly added the incraments and timestamps to it. I have some data in there so would prefer to use a migration to fix it as oppossed to a rollback.

I tried this but get an error:

Migration

```
Schema::table('hole_tee', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropPrimary('hole_tee_id_primary');
            $table->dropColumn('id');
            $table->dropTimestamps();   
            $table->primary(['hole_id', 'tee_id']);
});
```

Error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as
  a key (SQL: alter table `hole_tee` drop primary key)


  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as
  a key
```

Original Migration that Created the table

```
Schema::create('holes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->integer('scorecard_id');
            $table->integer('number');

            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::create('hole_tee', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->integer('hole_id');
            $table->integer('tee_id');
            $table->integer('yardage');
            $table->integer('par');
            $table->integer('handicap');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comment: I think is because of this: **$table->primary(['hole_id', 'tee_id']);**. You can't have two primary in your table, if these fields are foreign keys declare them like so.

Comment: @JordyGarcía thats composite primary which is allowed.

Comment: The problem is you have `hole_id', 'tee_id'` auto column, two auto column.....why you need two auto column, check the schema and update the column as not auto increment or auto something.

Comment: @webDev I am a bit confused. I have done a composite primary before that is not `auto column` , why is this `auto column`

Comment: As far as I understood your situation is you have Hole and Tee model having many to many relation using your this pivot table. If i am not wrong or my assumption is not wrong please check your pivit table and see the schema definition there should be multiple auto field. Would you please share the schema of the table that already has been created on your post

Comment: @webDev Just updated question

Comment: In this case dont remove the `id` from pivite table because its laravel default nature that we should have primary key as auto incremented id field. I mean just leave that there. Make your composite key as secondary key. Why you want extra burden on your head leave the ID as primary key and that make sense too because every record in a table should have unique identification

Comment: @webDev Just from taking lesson on Laracasts pivot tables dont need an auto increment id, the primary should be a combo of the to unique ids (tee and hole). I can just leave it, I was just tying to make it like I have learned.

Comment: did you try removing the id first and then making composite primary. separate migration one after another.

Comment: I got it working by dropping the column first, then dropping primary, then adding primary, the removing timestamps